# how to use BufferedStreams and ObjectStreams parallel

Tags: java, android, networking

I am having this big confusion for sending a File(eg .jpg) from my android client to my pc server. The problem is that I used ObjectStreams earlier to send other data and messages to and fro(encapsulated inside class objects). But now when I want to send an entire file, I first tried to encode bytes of the file into a byte array variable inside the class object and sent that object using ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(). But on pc side when I read the ObjectInputStream() back to bytearray, and stored the bytes into a file, the original image file got corrupted and useless.

After some reading I found out that I must use Buffering to get the exact file on the other side w/o corruption. But how can i use both ObjectStreams & OutputStream on a single socket connection at the same time.

Here's some code:

```
private ObjectOutputStream connectionOutput;
connectionOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
public void sendPacket(AbstractPacket packet) throws IOException {//'packet' contains all the data
    connectionOutput.writeObject(packet);
    connectionOutput.flush();
    connectionOutput.reset();
}
```

If I added another method like:

```
private BufferedOutputStream BufferedconnectionOutput;
private OutputStream outputStream;
outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();

public void sendPacket(File file) throws IOException {
  byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) file.length()];
  fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
  bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream);
  bufferedInputStream.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
  outputStream.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
}
```

If I used both of these on the sending side, how could i differentiate between ObjectStreams & OutputStream at the receiving side.

Comment: 'I must use BufferedStreams to get the exact file on the other side w/o corruption. '. That is nonsense.

Comment: You are not showing how you initialze the output streams. What is 'outputStream'. Pretty unclear code this.

Comment: As long as you do not show how you write with two methods to one output stream it makes little sense to ask how to read from an input stream.

Comment: @greenapps Sorry for the incomplete code, I was planning to use OutputStream and sending only the bytearray.